# IE media query javascript 'response' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm building a mobile-first site, and I'm stuck on the menu. 
Everything works great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari & Opera; as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BtbHn/1/).

But ofcourse, the pathetic excuse of a browser abortion, internet explorer, doesn't support media queries. So I started browsing around and found the javascript solution for the **I**diot **E**xperience media query problem. *(See what I did there?)* [Respond - by scottjehl](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

So I quickly implemented the script and grabbed my cake to start celebrating this victory over the oozing scrotum of the browser world. But alas, the script did absolutely nothing, and I slipped back into my microsoft induced depression.

I implemented the script into my header like so:

```
 <!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

And I added the comment before closing my mediaquery.

```
/*/mediaquery*/
```

Anyone got any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried with the script element embedded directly (without conditional comments), to see if the error might lay there?

Comment: Yep. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Had to do with my DOCTYPE.
Wasn't supporting older versions of IE.

This code fixed it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```